# Data structure: Circular Queue (in C)

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm doing a Uno Card game (in C) and I have a Circular Queue in this following order:

user -> player1 -> player2 -> player3

If any player put in the table a card that change the order of the game, would be in the opposite direction.

For example, if the user put the "reverse" card, I would have to dequeue every player and the, enqueue like that:

```
enqueue(player3);
enqueue(player2);
enqueue(player1);
enqueue(user);
```

If player1, dequeue everybody and then:

```
enqueue(user);
enqueue(player3);
enqueue(player2);
enqueue(player1);
```

If player2, dequeue everybody and then:

```
enqueue(player1);
enqueue(user);
enqueue(player3);
enqueue(player2);
```

If player3, dequeue everybody and then:

```
enqueue(player2);
enqueue(player1);
enqueue(user);
enqueue(player3);
```

It's terrible, isn't it? Put it in this way, like, one "if" to any case. I know that when someone put the "reverse" card the first thing to do is to dequeue everybody, but after that, is there a better way to enqueue following the thought above?

Comment: I am stupid - It is Sunday and students have been on the raz - hence unable/incapable of doing their homework. Why not give them incorrect answers :-)

Comment: what about using a double linked list and just changing the direction of parsing? i.e. swap the functionality of next and previous pointers?

Comment: Why not index into an array, and increment or decrement the index based on the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do this with a simple index and a step (+1 or -1)?

index = { player1, player2, player3, user }
step  = { clockwise, anticlockwise}

When a reverse card is played, just change the sign of the step?

- Start: index=player1, step=clockwise(+1)
- Repeat

  - Player plays card... if reverse, step = !step
  - Move to next player: index += step
- Until end

  Obviously, index needs bounds checking etc, but you get the principal